# htaccess replacing PHP file.php?id=dynamic_id with file/id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am wanting to use htaccess to make a url such as `http://example.com/news/news_post.php?id=dynamic_id` with a URL that looks like `http://example.com/news/news_post/dynamic_id`. So basically remove the .php file extension, as well as make `?id=dynamic_id` to `/dynamic_id` for my news_post.php page.

I have searched around at other examples to find something that may help, but I haven't been able to find anything that helps.

If someone can help me with this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've put up an answer up that gives you some scope to play with.

Comment: It's the other way around. The rewrite rules in `.htaccess` are used to internally convert a nice-looking URL into one that contains the variable names and everything you want to hide. It's the job of the script itself to generate nice-looking URLs.

Comment: @mdsmith98, Have you checked my answer? Is it working?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It is working. I have marked it as the answer :)

Comment: @mdsmith98, glad to help you, Happy coding!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

I tested this and it's working perfectly in my the system.

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
//above code is use for remove the .php 

RewriteRule ^news/news_post/([\w-]+) news_post.php?id=$1
```

**Index.php**

In this, I set the `href="javascript:void(0);"` and added `onclick` fucntion and pass the parameter to the function. In the function I set `window.location="news/news_post/"+user_id+"";` so your URL will look like `news/news_post/1`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$userdata['Id']=1;
 ?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myfunciton(<?php echo $userdata['Id']; ?>)">Click me</a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunciton(user_id){
                window.location="news/news_post/"+user_id+"";
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**news_post.php**

You can get the URL value using `$_REQUEST`

```
<?php 
echo $_REQUEST['id'];//output is 1
 ?>
```

**Output**

You will get output

```
domain.com/news/news_post/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickly Googling this and trying something out I came up with this...

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news/news_post/(\d+)*$ ./news_post.php/$1
```

**news_post.php**

```
<?php

//var_dump($_SERVER);

//var_dump(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

$url_segments = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
//var_dump($url_segments);

$id = $url_segments[3];

//var_dump($id);
echo __FILE__;
echo '<br>';
echo 'The Dynamic Id is '. $id;
```

So you can use whatever you like to get at the rest of the URL Parameters and do with them as you please...

**Note:** The var_dumps in news_post.php were used to quickly see what was going on and what was what...I left them there for you to play with if you so desire.

Of course you will change this to suit - I just guessed at what you may or may not have done or want.

**Example:**

```
http://phptutorials.com/news/news_post/1
```

**Result:**

```
/home/phptutorials/public_html/news_post.php
The Dynamic Id is 1
```

**Using a Central file to handle all requests.**
Going back to **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can now use index.php as the central "policeman" to show your pages for anything you like using the code above as shown in news_post.php. But that is outside of your question and something you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

> You Can add this code to your .htaccess file:
>
> **.htaccess**
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on     
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=dynamic_id($|&)
> RewriteRule ^news/news_post\.php$ /news/news_post/dynamic_id?&%{QUERY_STRING}
> ```